# iframe window loses the click addEventListener after click on a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app, that shows a 3rd party content within an iframe.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    
    const iframe = ref?.current?.contentWindow;
    const iframeWin = ref && ref?.current?.contentWindow || iframe;

    iframeWin.addEventListener('click', (event: Event ) => {
      console.log("click!");
   }); 
  }, []);

return (
    <iframe src="http://example.com"  loading='eager' id="myiframe" ref={ref} ></iframe>
)
```

This code works. I see the `click!` message on devtools.

My issue is that the page inside the iframe has a hyperlink, and after the user clicks that hyperlink, the eventlistener doesn't work any more.

It is just a simple hyperlink, opening the page inside the same window.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

try this,   Return a cleanup function to remove the event listener when the iframe's src attribute changes again

```
 useEffect(() => {
      const iframe = ref?.current?.contentWindow;
      const iframeWin = ref && ref?.current?.contentWindow || iframe;
    
      iframeWin.addEventListener('click', (event: Event) => {
        console.log("click!");
      });
    
      return () => {
        iframeWin.removeEventListener('click', (event: Event) => {
          console.log("click!");
        });
      };
    }, [src]); 
    
    return (
      <iframe src={src} loading='eager' id="myiframe" ref={ref} ></iframe>
    );
```

Comment: where do I declare `src`?

Comment: The frame `src` doesn't change. It is only the content that changes

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the content and href of the iframe changed.

At the end I used a hack to check the iframe url every second, and if it changed, then reapply the eventListener. This is the code:

```
  useEffect(() => {

    console.log("ref changed")
    
    const iframe = ref?.current?.contentWindow;
    const iframeWin = ref && ref?.current?.contentWindow || iframe;
    const iframeDoc = ref?.current?.contentDocument || iframeWin?.document as Document ;

    let handler = (event: Event ) => {
      console.log("click!");
     }

    var href = ref?.current?.contentWindow?.location?.href;

    setInterval(() => {
      let href_test = ref?.current?.contentWindow?.location?.href;
      if (href == href_test) return;
      href = href_test;
      console.log("href changed");
      iframeWin && iframeWin.addEventListener('click', handler);
    }, 1000);  

    iframeWin && iframeWin.addEventListener('click', handler);
 
    return () => {
      iframeWin && iframeWin.removeEventListener('click', handler);      
    }
                
  }, [ref?.current?.contentWindow?.location?.href]);
```